# Debugging RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

My goal is to count the number of wells in each county. I've verified the columns are correct as listed in the attribute table. Do I have a typing or formatting error? I wanted to pull county names from a list but I'm trying to T/S with one variable first.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.overWriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\GIS4080\\Week5\\Lesson5_Data"  

# Variables
wells = "Wells.shp"
counties = "COUNTIES.shp"
Wells_Intersect = "Wells_Intersect.shp"
Wells_Intersect_Layer = "Wells_Intersect_Layer"
input_f = ["Wells.shp", "COUNTIES.shp"]
Date_list = []
wellCnt = 0

# Process: Intersect
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(input_f, Wells_Intersect, "ALL", "", "INPUT")

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Wells_Intersect, Wells_Intersect_Layer)

# List County Names
countyList = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(counties, "COUNTY")]
#print countyList

# Count Wells in each County
#for cname in countyList:
cname = "YUMA"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Wells_Intersect_Layer, "COUNTY", '"COUNTY "= ' + cname) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        wellCnt = wellCnt + 1
        print cname, str(wellCnt)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "E:\GIS4080\Week5\L5_hw.py", line 32, in 
>     for row in cursor:
>   RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Comment: looks like `"COUNTY "` rather than `"COUNTY"` (space before the double-quote mark) in your `with` line

Comment: For debugging purposes you can wrap the with clause with a try..except in order to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juggling single quotes and double quotes can be a pain, but this should work:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Wells_Intersect_Layer, "COUNTY", '"COUNTY" = \'{}\''.format(cname)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
```

Although you could probably also get around it by specifying the Where clause separately:

```
# Count Wells in each County
#for cname in countyList:
countyField = '"COUNTY"'
cname = "YUMA"
whereclause = "{} = '{}'".format(countyField, cname)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Wells_Intersect_Layer, "COUNTY", whereclause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
```

Comment: Finally got my whereclause to work! Thanks. More study time on formatting is a must.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in your `where_clause`.

```
'"COUNTY "= ' + cname
```

You have a space between the attribute name and quotation mark instead of quotation mark and equal sign, which I think will throw it off.

Try instead:

```
"COUNTY = '{}'".format(cname)
"COUNTY = '" + cname + "'"    # this is the same, but I find it harder to read!
```

You need those quotation marks there to properly include `cname` as a string in the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting suggestions and example. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: String formatting requires single-quotes: `"COUNTY = '{:s}'".format(cname)`

Comment: @Vince thanks, I always mess that up when I'm going by memory and don't have a Python IDLE at hand.